# Subfolders in symfony controller folder

Tags: symfony

Is it good practice to add some subfolders to my Controller folder? It becomes difficult to find one that I need since after they become fifteen(and, besides, mix logic that I want to move to separate controllers), and I'm going to add more currently. I see clearly that all them belongs to different logical domains - entities and few other domains - like reports and etc, but all them, anyway, uses entities and services of my app bundle and I quite sure that I wouldnt separate them to different bundles.

Comment: to me it sounds reasonable to have a structure for controllers if they are belonging to different domains. but "mixed logic" smells like you should put this logic into services instead of controllers.

Comment: Yes you can ! It's what I am doing for a project, I have sections and sub-sections, so I have a sub-folder for each section containg stuff related to this specific section.

Comment: By 'mixed logic' I meant that some of their actions should be placed in separate controllers - my controller structute currently looks like:
-ClientController.php
-ClientViewController.php
-ContractController.php 
and etc. - so - most of them processing request containing entity data in terms of adding/deleting/updating it to database, but some also contains some heavyweight multi-level validations/statistics/reports - I currently moving this to new contollers which represents logical domains to which this actions really belongs to, incapsulating logic to the services where it possible.

Comment: Fortunately, this chaos wasn't ither my decision or decision of man, who was writing it  - was written by my good friend couple of years ago during his study for the company I currently working in in circumstnces while he didn't have clear requirements for the system and future development plans:) But this doesn't matter really, thank you for your replies - now I have understanding that nothing criminal in separaing controllers belonging to different logical domains represented by folders.

Answer (score -2):

Controller folder must have only Controller files nothing more. You can create sub-folders inside Controller folder but it should contain only controllers.

Good structure is like below:

- BusinessLogicBundle (Include services)
- CoreBundle (Controller, Form, Listeners, Helpers)
- EntityBundle (Entity, Commands, Validator)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But it is little bit too detailed - have clear understanding that conroller folder must contain controllers and only controllers.

Comment: Also, can you explain me - why shold I split up my app to few different bundles? If you have a link which describes reasons for that - would be happy to read it:)